# How to send filename with file from ASP .Net Core controller to Angular as a blob?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, blob

I have a controller in .Net Core which is sending a file to my angular application. The file is received in Angular as a blob. How can I send the filename from .Net Core with the file itself? My code below sets the filename on the client side, but I need the file name to be able to change dynamically.

ASP .Net Core Controller

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("downloadcompletes/{Id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadPartnerCompletes(Guid Id)
    {
        var list = await _projectService.DownloadPartnerCompletes(Id);

        foreach(var vendorParticipants in list.GroupBy(x => x.PartnerName))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.TableName = vendorParticipants.FirstOrDefault().PartnerName + " - " + vendorParticipants.FirstOrDefault().ProjectCode;
            dt.Columns.Add("PartnerName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("PanelListId", typeof(string));
            dt.AcceptChanges();

            string fileName = dt.TableName + ".xlsx";

            foreach (var i in vendorParticipants)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(i.PartnerName, i.PanelListID);
            }

            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(stream);
                    InMemoryFile file = new InMemoryFile();
                    file.FileName = fileName;
                    file.Content = stream.ToArray();
                    files.Add(file);
                }
            }
        }

     return File(files.FirstOrDefault().Content, "applicatication/xlsx", fileName);

    }
```

Angular Service

```
downloadPartnerCompletes(id: UUID): Observable<Blob> {
  console.log(id);
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/downloadcompletes/' + id, id, {responseType: 'blob'});
}
```

Angular Component

```
downloadPartnerCompletesZip() {
  this.exportFilesService.downloadPartnerCompletes(this.project.id).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: data.type, });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = url;
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';

  if (data.type === 'applicatication/xlsx')  {
    hiddenElement.download = 'PartnerCompletes.xlsx';
  } else {
  hiddenElement.download = 'PartnerCompletes.zip';
  }
  hiddenElement.click();
}, error => {
  this.alertify.error(error);
},
() => {
    this.alertify.success('Partner Completes Downloaded');
});
}
```

Comment: You probably already checked this, as I see a `console.log(data)` there, but don't you have the filename in the `data` object?

Comment: No, as the response type is of type blob it is no more than a string of bytes representing the file contents, not the file itself